# Sql query to find and sum orders placed in the morning throws error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a sql query, in sql server 2012, to find out how many orders were placed in the morning. The table name is Order_Data which has a column, Order_TimeStamp with the value when the order was placed. The following is my query:

```
select sum(case when 
substring(CONVERT(varchar,O.OrderTimestamp,108),1,2)>='05' 
and substring(CONVERT(varchar,O.OrderTimestamp,108),1,2)<='11' 
then 1 else 0) as orderCountTimeMorning 
from Order_Data O where 
o.email_address = 'abc@yahoo.com'
```

When I run this query I am getting "Incorrect syntax near ')'" error. This happens at the "then 1 else 0)" part of the query. I tried to match the brackets and they seem to match fine.

Comment: Please define "morning".

Comment: Orders placed before 12:00 noon. Thanks

Comment: But `00:00` - `05:00` is *before* noon. Also, I suggest declaring your length when using the `varchar` data type

Comment: The current syntax error that you are getting comes from a missing `end` in your case expression : `sum(case when ... then 1 else 0 end)`.

Comment: case is not good, better option is create a new table with your params and do join. is a better practice

Comment: Since you are not counting anything else, you should probably just move this logic to the `WHERE` clause, i.e.             `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Order_Data WHERE Email_Address  = 'abc@yahoo.com' AND DATEPART(HOUR, OrderTimeStamp) BETWEEN 5 AND 11;`    That way you are not reading a load of unnecessary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `datepart()`:

```
select sum(case when datepart(hour, ordertimestamp) between 5 and 11 
                then 1 else 0
           end) as orderCountTimeMorning 
from Order_Data O
where o.email_address = 'abc@yahoo.com';
```

Or, convert the value to a time:

```
select sum(case when convert(time, ordertimestamp) >= '05:00:00' and
                     convert(time, ordertimestamp) < '12:00:00'
                then 1 else 0
           end) as orderCountTimeMorning 
from Order_Data O
where o.email_address = 'abc@yahoo.com';
```

There is no need to convert date/time values to strings for such comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

It sound like what you really want is;

```
Select count(*) from Order_Data
where convert(time, ordertimestamp) >= '05:00:00' 
and convert(time, ordertimestamp) < '12:00:00'
and email_address = 'abc@yahoo.com'
```